# How to manage CRUD correctly of an input type "file"?

Tags: php, html, file, input

I'm wanting to create a form with multiple inputs of type "file", but I find some problems that I don't know which is the best way for continue.

Specifically I'm having problems with inputs type "file". To make it easier, suppose that the form only contains one type "file" input.

What I have done so far is the next.

Before submit:
In front-end I have two buttons for the input: Upload file, and remove uploaded file.
If click upload file I can attatch a file, and if a file was update, it is replaced with the new selected file.
If click remove button, the input is emptied.

On Submit Form:
When I submit the form. I save the file from file input in storage and save the url of the file in database.

On read / modify.
I re-use the same view to read/modify form. Then I pass the data and with JS I refill the form inputs.

Here is where I have the problem.
I know inputs of type "file" can't be filled for security reasons. Then I have the next problem:
If the input is empty is the same as if I had pressed the remove button. The input is empty, then, on submit, the field of database is updated to empty.

The solution I see is in PHP check if the input is set and not empty, if both conditions are true, then update database field. If both conditions not are true, then skip update of database field. But then I lost the functionality of remove.

I don't know how to manage correctly the create/modify/remove of "file" type input.

Thanks for your help, and sorry for the length of my question.

Comment: Why would that cause you to lose the "remove" functionality? That should be a separate operation which the user requests specifically, and not dependent on whether a form field was filled or not.

Comment: look.. this is all you need to know about file upload in php: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php .. anyway to answer your doubts, the file input field is just the way to deliver the input (of new files) to your page.. while the files you already own should be shown in some other way.. like some sort of collection rendered via hidden inputs that will be possible to change with the remove button before posting the form. The backend will check if any file was deleted and will perform the deletion.

Comment: Then I should do? Skip update of field when input is empty, but how can I indicate on form submit that the field must be removed?

Comment: as I tried to say before, let's say our scenario involves uploading only one file per submit. Your php script when invoked should check the list of files available on server and list them in the response as `<input type="hidden">` using some key identifying each one of them. Then each of those should have a way of showing its presence on the dom with a remove button that will remove that specific `input` from the dom if pressed. Once you submit the page, (with or without new file added), the page on the server should check the diff between that list and its files

Comment: Ahh okey. Now I understand. Thank you so much . Sorry about my little knowledge 